# Execute some part of code from another file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have few global functions, which I have defined as following in **main.js** like following:

```
Vue.prototype._isMobile = function () {
  return $(window).width() < 768
}
//Few more such things
```

I want to move to some other file say **util.js** like this:

```
return (function () {
  import Vue from 'vue'
  Vue.prototype._isMobile = function () {
    return $(window).width() < 768
  }
})();
```

and added following code in **main.js**

```
require('util.js')
```

I tried few more variants of this, But this does not work, I also tried exporting, importing but those also did not work. What should be better way of doing such thing.

### **Edit**

I tried suggestion to use plugin, I create file: **util.js** as follows:

```
Util.install = function (Vue, options) {
  Vue.prototype._isMobile = function () {
    return $(window).width() < 768
  }
}
```

and in **main.js**:

```
import Util from 'util'
Vue.use(Util)
```

However getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: plugin.apply is not a function

Comment: why aren't you using [plugins](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html)?

Comment: I'm sorry then. How have you tried to export and import those functions? What I'm currently doing in my project it's to "export function foo() {}" and then in my components I "import { foo } from '../helpers.js' sort of thing. Them I'm able to use that function in my component.

Comment: @Potray I am not trying to use those functions, mixins can do that thing, I was trying to have some code executed once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [plugins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) to make it easy and modular as I understand from your question.

Add this to **utils.js**

```
const customPlugin = {}

customPlugin.install = (Vue, options) => {
  Vue.prototype._isMobile = () => {
    return $(window).width() < 768
  }
}

export default customPlugin
```

and then in your `main.js` you can use it like any other plugin like:

```
import customPlugin from '/path/to/customPlugin'

Vue.use(customPlugin)
```

Comment: Made these changes, still getting the same error, as I updated in the question

Comment: I'll try a fiddle.

Comment: @Saurabh Just for clarification, `console.log(Util)` before `Vue.use(Util)` is?

Comment: Thanks, this is working now, It seems it was not working with `.vue` extension.